# pandas convert Hour index integer to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
   Date    Hour Actual      
2018-06-01  0   0.000000
2018-06-01  1   0.012000
2018-06-01  2   0.065000
2018-06-01  3   0.560000
...
```

I want to convert these Hour integer indexes and add to date so that it is a Pandas' datetime object.
The result should be like this:

```
       Date            Actual       
2018-06-01 00:00:00   0.000000
2018-06-01 01:00:00   0.012000
2018-06-01 02:00:00   0.065000
2018-06-01 03:00:00   0.560000
...
```

What would be an efficient way to do that? Does Panda provide functionality for converting integer indexes into datetime objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `time`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('Hour'), unit='H')
print (df)
                 Date  Actual
0 2018-06-01 00:00:00   0.000
1 2018-06-01 01:00:00   0.012
2 2018-06-01 02:00:00   0.065
3 2018-06-01 03:00:00   0.560
```