# How can you convert columns with hours integers into a datetime pandas index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

EDIT:

I have a dataframe with the following shape:

| date | 1 | ... | 48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 15.5 | ... | 12.1 |
| 02-01-2021 | 20.5 | ... | 10.3 |

The values for each **half-hour** are given in each of the columns (1-48).

How can I convert this into a single series with the datetime index having the time (hh:mm) and a single column with the values, as below:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 01:00 | 15.5 |
| 01-01-2021 01:30 | 14.5 |
| 01-01-2021 24:00 | 12.1 |
| ... | ... |
| 01-02-2021 01:00 | 20.5 |
| 01-02-2021 01:30 | 18.5 |

Preferably, I'd like to avoid iterating over all columns and all rows and would prefer using the pd.to_datetime() functionality.

Example dataframe below:

```
data = [['01-01-2021', 15.5, 12.1],
        ['02-01-2021', 20.5, 10.3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', '1', '48'])
```

As suggested, I've tried this:

```
df=df.melt(id_vars=['date'], value_vars=[col for col in df.columns[1:]], value_name='value',var_name='Hour')
```

This can work for hours:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + \
pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'].astype(int), unit='H')
```

However, how can I add each **half hour** to the datetime rather than hourly values?

EDIT:

The following works for half hours:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + \
    pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'].astype(int)/2, unit='H')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert Hour index integer to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473972/pandas-convert-hour-index-integer-to-datetime)

Comment: Not completely, I've added an edit to the question.

Comment: That works for half hours 

`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + \
    pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'].astype(int)/2, unit='H')`

Answer (score 2):

Try with `melt`:

```
out = df.melt('date', )

# is `02-01` Jan 2nd?
out['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(out['date'], dayfirst=True)
               + pd.to_timedelta(out['variable'].astype(int), unit='H')
              )
```

Output:

```
                 date variable  value
0 2021-01-01 01:00:00        1   15.5
1 2021-01-02 01:00:00        1   20.5
2 2021-01-02 00:00:00       24   12.1
3 2021-01-03 00:00:00       24   10.3
```

Comment: what about in the case of half hours rather than hours? See the edited question. Thanks